# Is it possible to draw an EK diagram for the infinite square well?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electronic-band-theory

EK diagram is usually talked about in the context of semiconductors, but can we draw an EK diagram for situations that don't involve semiconductors?

Comment: E-K diagrams are most often used (in my particular experience) for band structures in crystals. They apply to far more than semiconductors - you find them for metals and insulators as well. What is not clear to me is what you expect for an E-K diagram for an infinite square well - there is no crystal momentum there.

Answer (score 1):

You asked two separate questions:

> Is it possible to draw an EK diagram for the infinite square well?

No. Such a diagram only makes sense if the potential is periodic, and that's not the case for an infinite square well.

> can we draw an EK diagram for situations that don't involve semiconductors?

Absolutely. You can do it anywhere you have a periodic potential (e.g. metals and superlattices).